# Return count of column based on previous data

Tags: python, mysql, sql, count

How can I get count user_id group by type, country_code and date where current type is D or A and previous type was also D or A.

e.g the query should return for country_code 1 and Type D => count(user_id) = 1
and country_code 2 and Type A => count(user_id) = 1

```
id  country_code Type user_id  Date
1   1        D     1       01-01-14
2   1        ND    1       02-01-14
3   1        D     1       03-01-14
4   1        D     1       04-01-14
5   2        D     1       05-01-14
6   2        ND    2       06-01-14
7   2        A     1       07-01-14
8   2        A     1       08-01-14
```

Comment: Because your count depends on what comes 'previous', wouldn't that mean you also have to group by date? Because what comes prior is dependent on what the current date is. I am not sure what you've said you're after makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the following:

```
select type, country_code, date, count(distinct user_id)
  from tbl x
 where type in ('D', 'A')
   and exists
 (select 1
          from tbl y
         where y.type in ('D', 'A')
           and y.country_code = x.country_code
           and y.date <= (select max(z.date)
                           from tbl z
                          where z.date < x.date
                            and z.type = y.type
                            and z.country_code = y.country_code))
 group by type, country_code, date
```

I assumed you wanted a distinct count of user IDs, if that's not the case remove the distinct keyword.

Here is a sql fiddle test with your data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c85e/4/0

Comment: thanks for reply, but isn't the result should be 2 rows as there is one occurrence of A and D for same country.

Comment: But on more than one date (as discussed before). You have to group by date if you're going to count rows that are prior to each date.

Comment: It should have been <= though (see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c85e/4/0 ). For example w/ country 2, it is showing that the count is for rows prior to 7/1/14, and for 8/1/14, there are 2 rows prior. Clearly 7 and 8 show 2 instances for the same country that are A or D (per your criteria) and each of them have rows prior.

Comment: I think I could not explain my problem very well, so what i really want is to count user ids when their current type and previous type is   A or D. I dont know should i consider date or not. for example if today type is A and and user id is 1 and yesterday it was also same or type was D then i want to count as 1 for these matches not two instances of A or D

Comment: I don't see how the count would ever be any different then 1, if that is the case. Do you just want a list of users for each country whose current (highest date) type is A or D at country X and whose previous type (next highest date) is A or D at country X?

Comment: suppose in my sample data the second row type is also D then i want to have total counts of 3 for type D as the all other data is same except date and type is also previous type which is also D